# Linking and getting customized outputs mysql

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have created customer tbale which has all customer info,product tbale which has all product info,sales tbale which references both cus id and productid in sales table to the customer and product tabel using foreign keys as of below,BTW sales table pic is on the last line
[customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7g4i.jpg)

[Product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp8CR.jpg)

SELECT productid FROM sales
JOIN customer ON customer.customeridno=sales.customerid
WHERE customer.customername='Mohan';

yes ofc i get 5000-which is the productid for the specified name;But is there any way that i can display productname which is being referenced by product id here(forein key)
sales table-  postimg.org/image/94u2c1wnn/-salestable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you will also need to `JOIN` the `product` table to get the name

Try something like

```
SELECT product.productname 
FROM sales 
JOIN customer ON customer.customeridno=sales.customerid 
JOIN product ON product.productid = sales.productidno 
WHERE customer.customername='Mohan';
```

Assuming sales has a FK `productidno`

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause with inner query like this:

```
SELECT productname
FROM product
WHERE productid in (
   SELECT productid FROM sales
   JOIN customer
   ON customer.customeridno=sales.customerid
   WHERE customer.customername='Mohan'
);
```